# fine-grained access for GCP OSLogin / osAdminLogin?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

Is it possible to control which users/groups get which sudo privileges?  Or is it an all-or-nothing proposition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to give fine grained authorization to users using [Google IAM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.osAdminLogin).

Project and instance-level administrators can use IAM to [grant SSH access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) to a user's Google identity without granting a broader set of privileges. For example, you can grant a user [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users) to log into the system, but not the ability to run commands such as `sudo`. Google checks these permissions to determine whether a user can log into a VM instance.

If you want to know more about the [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute-engine-roles) you can configure in a GCE instance, here is the material you could use.